# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on Lenovo yoga 530 ryzen 5

Tags: 18.04, lenovo

I need to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on my new PC (Lenovo yoga 530 AMD ryzen5), although I cannot make the boot system read the ISO file on my USB flash drive. What can I do? (I do not have a CD Player on this PC)

Answer (score 0):

[This should really be a comment.. but I dont have the privlieges]

1) Did you disable secure boot? Go to your BIOS and disable it.

2) Did your correctly flash the iso file to your flash drive? (Rufus or Balena Etcher recommended)

3) When you have plugged the flashed flash drive in, enter the BIOS and make sure you are booting from the flash drive and not your laptop's internal storage. If you boot from your internal storage, you will always boot into the default OS (Probably windows 10 for you). Change the default bootable device in the BIOS to your flashdrive.